# $\int\limits_0^t \sqrt{V(\tau)}\ d\tau = ?$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to understand an integration step done in a video lecture.

$V$ is a function of a single variable, and we know that it admits the inequality $V'(\tau)\leq-\alpha \sqrt{V(\tau}$ where $\alpha > 0 $

The lecturer then goes on to say that by integrating both sides from $0$ to $t$ we get the inequality

$\sqrt{V(t)} \leq -\frac{1}{2}\alpha t+\sqrt{V(0)}$

I don't understand why that's true. $\int_{0}^{t}V'(\tau)d\tau = V(t)-V(0)$ of course, but what's $\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{V(\tau)}d\tau$? Can this be done by parts maybe?

Comment: Note that $\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{V(t)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{V'(t)}{\sqrt{V(t)}}$. Now integrate both sides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your inequality can be written as
$$\left(\sqrt{V(t)}\right)' = \frac{V'(t)}{2\sqrt{V(t)}} \le -\frac12\alpha$$

so integrating gives

$$\sqrt{V(t)} - \sqrt{V(0)} =  \int_0^t\left(\sqrt{V(s)}\right)'\,ds \le -\frac12\int_0^t \alpha\,ds = -\frac12\alpha t$$
which is your desired inequality.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks.